# How to Check File Exist or Not in WinRAR, 7Zip, Zip, Tar, Winzip in C#

Tags: c#, zip, 7zip, winrar, ionic-zip

In my project I'm uploading a `7Zip`, `Zip`, `Tar`, `Winzip`, `WinRAR`, and etc file.

Now I want to check if particular file is present in uploaded archive using C#.

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: What have you tried ? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Why do you need to check if it exists *in* WinRAR, 7Zip, Zip, Tar or WinZip as opposed to just checking if it exists?

Comment: Something like here :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5978567/detecting-if-a-file-is-an-archive-using-7zip

Comment: In my project, the user will upload a WinRAR, 7Zip, Zip, Tar, or Winzip file but for few validations such as uploaded zip contains valid files/folders, there is any virus within uploaded files or any invalid files or any other resources or files which we not allowing, etc.

Comment: i.g, I have 3 different file ABC1.txt, ABC2.txt, and ABC3.txt now I creating WinRAR file for the same. Now as per my record WinRAR file is ok there are 3 different files, but now inbetween someone open that file in the server and by mistake delete any file supposes ABC2.txt is deleted then while I extract  WinRAR file then ABC2.txt will not found and as per I further depended/functionality of my project logic my code will throw custom exception file ABC2.txt FILE NOT FOUND.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307774/how-can-i-list-the-contents-of-a-zip-folder-in-c

Comment: @NikunjSatasiya For .zip is simple using deflate streams in C#. For .rar is more complicated because it is a closed format, you'll need a licence or crack it. Fir .tar and .7zip I don't know, but you'll have read their official docs in order how to read this file formats.

Comment: @ JavierSilvaOrtíz Thanks, for your valuable response I will go thought your solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.OpenRead(zipPath))
{
    Boolean isFolderExist = false;

    foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries) {
        if (entry.FullName.Contains("PDFsDir/")) {                       
            isFolderExist = true;
        }
    }

    if (isFolderExist) {
        Console.WriteLine("the folder which name is pictures exists in zip file");
        if(entry.FileName.Contains( "PDFsDir" )==true) {
            Console.WriteLine("File Exist");
        }
    } else {
        Console.WriteLine("the folder doesn't exist ");
    }
}
```

Comment: For Best example to read the in side the zip or rar file: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.zipfile.openread?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Hi Manish, it will work for all extensions such as rar, 7z, zip, tar?